# Navigation slow because of listview

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, navigation

I am making a UWP app where I navigate to a page with a listview.
In the constructor, I call an asynchronous function to set the itemsource of the listview. The data is stored locally, but this takes some time to filter and sort the list. Although I call an asynchronous function, navigation does not occur until the itemsource for the listview is set.

```
public FriendsPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    RefreshListViews();
}
//I tried both these versions: in the first one, 
//the app clearly takes one extra second to navigate to the page.
private async void RefreshListViews(){
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Listview.ItemsSource = …;
}

private async void RefreshListViews(){
    await Dispatcher.RunAsyn(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,() => {
        Listview.ItemsSource = …;
    });
}
```

How can I fix this, so the app first navigates and then filters/sorts/populates the listview?

Comment: where is the code for navigation?

Comment: The problem is when navigating towards this page. It is just something like this: rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(FriendsPage)); in my mainpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding extra logic in the constructor of your `FriendsPage`, which is costly since it delays the visual rendering of the page, even if such operation "would" be performed in a non-blocking manner.

Solution? Handle the responsibility of running this code to the event which is built-in the `Page` class, and which handles navigation onto it. That event is [OnNavigatedTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto), and is called when the `Frame` has locked the `FriendsPage` has its current Page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
      // Refresh List Views
}
```

On the same article, you can check the situations where you might want to use the `Loaded` event instead.

I would also suggest to not create a fire-and-forget asynchronous method, but instead change the signature of your asynchronous operation to instead return an awaitable o:

```
private async Task RefreshListViews()
{
   // Do stuff 
}
```

And *await* its execution on the navigation event!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I did try OnNavigatedTo with all possible async combinations before and it did not work.
But combining this with the `frame.loaded += frame_loaded` on OnNavigatedTo and `frame.loaded -= frame_loaded` on OnNavigatedFrom solved my problem. Thanks